# Rails 4 .dat import postgreSQL and ajax search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to implement a flight search system in Rails 4.

And I found [this resource](http://openflights.org/data.html),

My questions are:

1. **I've downloaded the airports.dat file and it contains chunks of data, do I need to import those data into psql? If yes, how?**
2. **If I just need the airport ID and name values, how do I selectively import them?**
3. **If I want to implement ajax load airport name just like the way expedia.com did, would it be buggy(slow loading time) if I use VPSs like Digitalocean?**

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that read line by line, and parse every line by the comma (","). Then you have enough information to insert to database.

For example:

`flight1 = '507,"Heathrow","London","United Kingdom","LHR","EGLL",51.4775,-0.461389,83,0,"E","Europe/London"'`

Then you can get the ID by call `flight1.split(",")[0]`

The speed of your search function is affected by your search algorithm and how do you implement the logic, and isn't affected by using a VPS.